# Getting corresponding and non corresponding values in many to many table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table structure in my sql like following:

Brand -> BrandUser <- Users

The BrandUser table contains userId and brandId columns. I need to get ALL brands for which are registered, and for which they are not registered.

So for instance lets say I have userId = 2 which is repeating itself twice in brandUser table and I send the userId = 2... I need to get those TWO records, as well as the rest of the brands from Brands table for which user DOES NOT HAVE VALUE in BRANDUSER table. I have written the following query:

```
   $col = "
       u.id,
       u.username,
       u.firstName,
       bu.active,
       bu.userId,
       b.name";

   $sql = " SELECT $col
              FROM brands b
              LEFT JOIN branduser bu on bu.brandId = b.id
              LEFT JOIN users u on bu.userId = u.id
             WHERE bu.userId = $userId";

 $brandListUserRegistered = $this->getBrandModel()->getBrandsForUser($sql);
```

And this is the getBrandsForUser action which executes the query:

```
public function getBrandsForUser($sql){
    $resultSet = $this->dbAdapter->query($sql,Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    return $resultSet->toArray();
}
```

The main thing I'm focusing on right now is the query itself... with the query above I only get brand records for the user that actually HAS corresponding records in branduser table, and thats not what I want... :/

Comment: When left join, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior! (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: Could you reply in a form of answer so that I can see what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use BrandUser as your base table and then left join to the other tables;

```
SELECT
$col
FROM BrandUser bu
LEFT JOIN Brand b
    ON bu.brandId = b.id
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON bu.userId = u.id
WHERE bu.userId = $userId
```

This way you will just return NULL values if there is not corresponding data in the Brand table.

My apologies, I misread your question, try changing the WHERE clause so that it is included in the join;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
$col
FROM Brand b
LEFT JOIN BrandUser bu
    ON bu.brandId = b.id
    AND bu.userId = $userId
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON bu.userId = u.id
```

Comment: My apologies, I read your question incorrectly. I've updated the answer, give that one a try.

Comment: Rich Benner, I think it actually works, one sec ill just check the results.. :)

Comment: I'm getting duplicate results as well... but it returns like 700 results lol... Should I do a group by bu.brandId or something like that??

Comment: I'm not sure which columns you're using in the select, but if you just want to remove duplicates then you could just do a SELECT DISTINCT. I've added that in my answer.

Comment: Hi Rich, these are the columns:SELECT u.id,u.username,u.firstName,bu.active,bu.userId,b.name
FROM Brands b
LEFT JOIN BrandUser bu
    ON bu.brandId = b.id
    AND bu.userId = 487
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON bu.userId = u.id

Comment: If you're not doing any aggregation (sum, count) then I'd probably just stick with a select distinct. You can do a group by if you would prefer but that's just going to make your code longer and produce the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114097/discussion-between-perkes456-and-rich-benner).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the answer, but an improvement!

When `left join`, put the right side table's conditions in the `ON` clause to get true left join behavior! (When in `WHERE`, you get regular inner join result.)

```
SELECT $col
FROM brands b
LEFT JOIN branduser bu on bu.brandId = b.id
                       AND bu.userId = $userId
LEFT JOIN users u on bu.userId = u.id
```

Comment: Hey Jarlih, I tried it and I get duplicate results in my query result... Perhaps I should do a group by bu.brandId or something like that??

Comment: I say the same as Rich Brenner, try `SELECT DISTINCT`!

Comment: It works it works it worksss!!!! Thank you guys sooooo much!!  You have no idea how much this helped me!! Oh goodness!! :D